# PHP: output_buffering ini option is ignored

Tags: php

From `phpinfo()` output:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini

output_buffering => 0 => 0
```

Inside `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

Php script results of `ini_get('output_buffering')` is `0`

I have tried to enable output_buffering at the begining of php script with `ini_set('output_buffering',4092)`, but it's not helping.

What can cause this behavior?

Thanks ;)

Comment: You did restart your web server, didn’t you?

Comment: Are you running PHP through the apache module?  If so, check your apache configuration to make sure it's not setting output buffering with php_admin_value.  Once apache sets an ini value using php_admin_value, it's locked in;  you can no longer change the setting using ini_set, and it will also override any value provided in your php.ini.  Try looking at the return value of the ini_set() call;  ini_set will return the previous value on success, and FALSE on failure.  If ini_set('output_buffering',4092)===FALSE, odds are good that it's caused by Apache.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that, no matter what, the value always seems to be "0" when using CLI SAPI. At least I couldn't retrieve it or change it via CMD in Windows XP. In fact, not even after changing Apache's configuration or php.ini did `ini_get()` show anything but "0". And I have no `php_admin_value` or `php_value` directives in any of my configuration files.

Comment: @user966939 so how did you see the actual value of the `output_buffering`?

Comment: @KelvinLowEeHahn It's been so long. I don't know what I meant by "couldn't retrieve it", but I assume I just did `var_dump(ini_get('output_buffering'));` to see the actual value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have multiple php.ini files.

Do a search on your system for other php.ini files around.

Another note, output_buffering can not be set via ini_set as it is a PHP_INI_PERDER setting. See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering